# Need help in getting data from multiple table using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am getting details in list format using this query, in that I am also getting user id.

```
reportProblemsList = objEntities.ReportProblems.ToList();
```

Now I want to get user details based on that user id from users table. So I have tried with foreach loop as per below.

```
foreach(var item in reportProblemsList)
{
   userdetails = objEntities.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == item.Userid).ToList();
}
```

Now I want to add this all userdetails in list and then access it. Below is my full code.

```
List<ReportProblem> reportProblemsList = new List<ReportProblem>();
List<User> userdetails = new List<User>();

reportProblemsList = objEntities.ReportProblems.ToList();

foreach(var item in reportProblemsList)
{
   userdetails = objEntities.Users.Where(x => x.UserId == item.Userid).ToList();
}

reportProblemsList.Add(userdetails);
```

But not able to get it working..any idea.

Thanks

Comment: How about `var reportProblemsList = objEntities.ReportProblems.Include(r => r.User).ToList()`? (if type `ReportProblem` has this property?)

Comment: What exactly are you returning from this function? What output do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you database is correctly designed from the given information, there is a high probability that your `ReportProblem` object has also the property `User` of type `User`. If this is the case you can instruct EF core to include such nested properties in your query by doing something like this:

```
var reportProblemsList = objEntities.ReportProblems
    .Include(report => report.User)
    .ToList();
```

If you don't have this property you have to create an anonymous type to hold the tuple:

```
var reportsWithUsers = objEntities.ReportProblems
    .Join(objEntities.Users, r => r.UserId, u => u.UserId, (Report, User) => (Report, User)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: If I want to add this list of userdetails in reportProblemsList then I am using AddRange but it is not adding values. Like this -  reportProblemsList.AddRange(userdetails);

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you need a list users who reported the issue.

```
var userIds = objEntities.ReportProblems.Select(q=> q.Userid).ToList();
List<User> userdetails = objEntities.Users.Where(x => userIds.Contains( x.UserId)).ToList();
```

Comment: if I want to add this list of userdetails in reportProblemsList then I am using AddRange but it is not adding values. Like this -  reportProblemsList.AddRange(userdetails);